# Selenium Framework

Tags: testing

If an interviewer asks, "Explain about Selenium Framework," What points do we need to focus on?
Do we need to explain about JUNIT or testNG (whichever we are using on our project) or the process we are following in our test automation?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is an automation tool. This is different to a testing tool, though automation tools are commonly used for testing purposes.

If I were interviewing you, I would probably want to know about:

- difficulties you'd encountered in setting up your tests using
  Selenium and how you overcame them;
- whether you recorded tests using
  the IDE or wrote them using WebDriver or a mixture of the two, and
  why you made that decision;
- how you structured your tests to keep
  them maintainable and easy to understand;
- whether you used automated tests to engage the business and get developers, testers and analysts talking
- your thoughts on the difference between Selenium and its other competitors like QTP.

Selenium tests usually focus on the full system rather than units of code, so you're more likely to get questions about BDD tools like JBehave or Cucumber than lower-level unit testing tools like JUnit or TestNG. Having said that, there's no reason why you can't use unit-testing tools with a DSL to run scenarios, so be prepared to answer questions on whichever approach you've taken or would recommend.